# Can we use a likert scale of 0 to 5 for SEM analysis?

Tags: regression, structural-equation-modeling, likert, mplus, amos

I am learning to do SEM analysis and have finished the data collection. In my questionnaire I have scales measured from $0$ to $5$ which measure emotions ($0$ = not feeling it at all to $5$ feeling it strongly). Now someone told me I SEM cannot use a scale with $0$ in it.

He is using AMOS. I heard Mplus can accommodate it. Does anybody know if this is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using a Likert-scale test, your variable here is inherently ordinal, though often they are treated as continuous. Zero probably doesn't have an actual meaningful value here, so it could just as easily be $1$ to $6$ and the outcomes wouldn't change much so long as you are not treating them as continuous in estimation. I'm guessing that their issue is that they are treating your variable here as continuous, which is anyway wrong per Kline (2023):

> Results from computer simulation studies generally indicate that use
> of estimators for continuous variables to analyze measurement models
> with Likert items as indicators is potentially problematic. For
> example, Rhemtulla et al. (2012) reported that for Likert items with
> fewer than 5 response categories, the robust ML method for continuous
> variables generated biased estimates of factor correlations and it
> generated standard errors that were generally too small. This
> distortion generally inflates the rate of Type I errors in
> significance tests of parameter estimates. Values of model test
> statistics, such as mean-and-variance adjusted chisquares that correct
> for nonnormality (Chapter 10), were generally too high when (1)
> population response distributions were marked skewed, or asymmetrical,
> and (2) patterns of asymmetry alternated over items in the same model.
> Under these conditions, the chi-square test rejected too many
> correctly specified models.

The reason I bring this up is because structural equation modeling is built to deal with different types of data, and the ordinal case is certainly manageable. I am not as familiar with Mplus or AMOS for SEM, but I am familar enough with `lavaan` in R to note that the `ordered` argument in the typical SEM functions treats the data as ordinal, as shown [here](https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/cat.html) and below in R syntax (w/ my own annotations):

```
#### Convert Data to Ordered ####
Data[,c("item1",
        "item2",
        "item3",
        "item4")] <-
    lapply(Data[,c("item1",
                   "item2",
                   "item3",
                   "item4")], ordered)

#### Fit Model ####
fit <- cfa(myModel, data = myData,
           ordered = c("item1","item2",
                       "item3","item4"))
```

Some discussion on how to do this in Mplus can be found [here](https://www.statmodel.com/discussion/messages/9/20451.html?1460325116).

##### Reference

Kline, R. B. (2023). Principles and practice of structural equation modeling (5th ed.). The Guilford Press.

Answer (score 1):

With ordinal data, you would typically use polychoric correlations and DWLS/WLSMV estimation (rather than covariances and maximum likelihood estimation) in CFA and SEM. Both lavaan and Mplus automate the process when indicators are defined as (ordered) categorical (ordinal). Here are some additional references:

Finney, S. J., & DiStefano, C. (2006). Non-normal and categorical data in structural equation modeling. In G. R. Hancock & R. O. Mueller (Eds.), *Structural equation modeling: A second course*. Greenwich, CT: Information Age Publishing.

Li, C.-H. (2016). The performance of ML, DWLS, and ULS estimation with robust corrections in structural equation models with ordinal variables. *Psychological Methods, 21*(3), 369–387. https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000093

Rhemtulla, M., Brosseau-Liard, P. É., & Savalei, V. (2012). When can categorical variables be treated as continuous? A comparison of robust continuous and categorical SEM estimation methods under suboptimal conditions. *Psychological Methods, 17*(3), 354-373.